# Parsing XML and adding new data with Python

Tags: python, xml

Parsing XML and adding new data with Python

Im trying to use Python for a task at hand.
I have an XML file with Google Earth data, and I need to add extra lines based on values found.
A piece of the file looks like this:

```
<Placemark>
<name>point1</name>
            <LookAt>
           <longitude>-80.08115898513155</longitude>
           <latitude>26.46738083560542</latitude>
                <altitude>0</altitude>
                <heading>2.100279283904433e-011</heading>
                <tilt>0</tilt>
                <range>1000.000208146521</range>
                <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#msn_wht-blank130010</styleUrl>
        </Placemark>
```

I need to get the values of lat/long and add additional information using those values, like this:

```
    <Placemark>
        <name>point1</name>
        <LookAt>
       <longitude>-80.08115898513155</longitude>
       <latitude>26.46738083560542</latitude>
            <altitude>0</altitude>
            <heading>2.100279283904433e-011</heading>
            <tilt>0</tilt>
            <range>1000.000208146521</range>
            <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        </LookAt>
        <styleUrl>#msn_wht-blank130010</styleUrl>
    </Placemark>
 <LatLonAltBox>
 <north>26.477380835605423</north>
 <south>26.45738083560542</south>
 <east>-80.07115898513155</east>
 <west>-80.09115898513156</west>
 </LatLonAltBox>
```

Basically I have to use the lat/long values, and construct a box around with 0.01 degrees difference.
Would would be the easiest way to accomplish this?
(I have a file with 20 thousands of those placemarks)

Not sure if it matters, but Im working on Mac OSX Sierra

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use Python's ["elementree"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) XML parser library.  It has all the capabilities you need and in my opinion the easiest of the built-in parsers to use. Use ["os.walk"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) to find each xml file you need to parse, then parse each file, and then overwrite them with the new modified XML tree containing your additional tags.